# How to ensure output from "tee" is shown when used in a script run under systemd

Tags: systemd, journald, stdout, tee

I have a script that I'm running under `systemd` which has some debug logs that I'd like to send to both stdout (which should end up in the system journal, viewable with `journalctl`) as well as to a log file on my filesystem.

Typically I'd reach for `tee` to accomplish this (write to stdout and files), and it works fine when I run the script on its own (I see all my logs on my console as well as in my log file), but when I run it under `systemd` I'm missing a bunch of the output from `tee` in the system journal (although all logs *are* present in the log file).

I've tried a few things that haven't solved the problem:

- `stdbuf` (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25548995/209050) for forcing line buffered output) in my `ExecStart=` in my service file.
- `StandardOutput=journal+console` in my service file (`DefaultStandardOutput` is unset in `/etc/systemd/system.conf`, so it has the default value of `journal`).
- Removed the `tee`, so the `echo` just writes directly to stdout. When I do this I *do* see all of the logs in the system journal (but I lose my log file). I guess I could make my own `tee` with a function that does two `echo`s (once to the logfile, once to stdout), but that feels kind of hacky. I would prefer to use `tee`, which already exists for this purpose...

I've reproduced this issue on the Manjaro and Ubuntu (`systemd 249 (249.4-2-manjaro)` and `systemd 245 (245.4-4ubuntu3.5)`), but I *can't* reproduce it on Debian 11 (`systemd 247 (247.3-6)`). I don't see any glaring difference in any of my configs under `/etc/systemd` between the working Debian system and the non-working Manjaro system. I'm not sure what other system configurations could be affecting this...

I have full repro instructions over [here](https://github.com/mgalgs/systemd-tee-output-issue).

#### My script

Lives at `/tmp/tee_test.sh`.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

LOGFILE=/tmp/testtee.log
echo > "$LOGFILE"
echo "i like pie" | tee -a "$LOGFILE"

i=2
while :; do
    echo "i shall eat $i slices of pizza" | tee -a "$LOGFILE"
    ((i++))
    sleep 1
done
```

#### My systemd unit

Lives at `~/.config/systemd/user/tee_test.service` and is loaded with `systemctl --user daemon-reload` each time I change it.

```
[Unit]
Description=Test teeing under systemd

[Service]
# same result with either of the following two variants
ExecStart=/tmp/tee_test.sh
# ExecStart=stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 /tmp/tee_test.sh

# same result with or without this guy
StandardOutput=journal+console

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

#### Logs in system journal

Viewing with `journalctl --user -x -u tee_test.service`. I only see a subset of the logs.

```
Oct 20 09:49:03 grinchel systemd[2678]: Started Test teeing under systemd.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit UNIT has finished successfully
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://forum.manjaro.org/c/support
░░
░░ A start job for unit UNIT has finished successfully.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 8193.
Oct 20 09:49:26 grinchel tee_test.sh[399363]: i shall eat 25 slices of pizza
Oct 20 09:49:40 grinchel tee_test.sh[400047]: i shall eat 39 slices of pizza
Oct 20 09:49:48 grinchel tee_test.sh[400430]: i shall eat 47 slices of pizza
Oct 20 09:49:49 grinchel tee_test.sh[400496]: i shall eat 48 slices of pizza
Oct 20 09:49:50 grinchel tee_test.sh[400529]: i shall eat 49 slices of pizza
Oct 20 09:49:51 grinchel tee_test.sh[400595]: i shall eat 50 slices of pizza
Oct 20 09:50:14 grinchel tee_test.sh[401790]: i shall eat 73 slices of pizza
Oct 20 09:50:27 grinchel systemd[2678]: Stopping Test teeing under systemd...
```

#### Logs in log file

In my log file I see all of the logs.

```
i like pie
i shall eat 2 slices of pizza
i shall eat 3 slices of pizza
i shall eat 4 slices of pizza
i shall eat 5 slices of pizza
i shall eat 6 slices of pizza
i shall eat 7 slices of pizza
[...many similar lines snipped -- they ARE all present in sequence as expected...]
i shall eat 84 slices of pizza
i shall eat 85 slices of pizza
i shall eat 86 slices of pizza
```

Any ideas what's going on here? How can I make sure that all of the output from `tee` shows up in my system journal?

Comment: Have you tried looking at what happens if you don't use `tee` and just let it go to the journal only? Do you get complete output then?

Comment: @Ginnungagap yeah, if I remove the `tee` I do see all of the output. Adding this to the list of things I've tried in my post.